# Call JavaScript method from Java React Native

Tags: java, react-native

I am new to React Native but would like to know if it is possible to call React Native JavaScript method from Java? I have a niche device that has a physical button that I would like to use to trigger a method when pressed.

I have seen the following plugin https://github.com/artemyarulin/react-native-eval but the Android implementation appears to be out of date.

I have googled around but all the examples I can find reference calling Java methods from React Native not the other way around.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have tried to implement a solution using the method suggested by @ide below. Here's my attempt so far:

In my MainActivity I have:

```
private String latestBarcode = "";

...

public String getLastestBarcode() {
  return this.latestBarcode;
}

public void setLatestBarcode(String barcode) {
  this.latestBarcode = barcode;
}

@Override
public void onBarcodeEvent(final BarcodeReadEvent event) {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
      String barcodeData = event.getBarcodeData();
      String tstp = event.getTimestamp();
      setLatestBarcode(barcodeData);
      Log.d("MainActivity", " TEST - barcodeData "+ barcodeData + " tstp : "+ tstp);
    }
  });
}
...
```

This code gets a barcode value from the device when a user presses the physical hardware button.

In my custom React Native module

```
@ReactMethod
public void latestBarcode(Callback callback) {
  final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();

  if(activity != null && activity instanceof MainActivity){
    callback.invoke(((MainActivity) activity).getLastestBarcode());
  }
  else {
    callback.invoke("");
  }
}
```

This method takes the value and exposes it to React Native. This works I can read the value but I need to trigger a method when the user presses the button so here is my React Native module as it stands now in all its entirety:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

// Import MainActivity
import com.myapp.MainActivity;

public class HoneywellCT50Module extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private ReactContext reactContext;

  public HoneywellCT50Module(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }


  @ReactMethod
  public void latestBarcode(Callback callback) {
    final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();

    if(activity != null && activity instanceof MainActivity){
      WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap(); // <--- Added WritableMap
      sendEvent("BarcodeRecieved", params); // <--- Added sendEvent

      callback.invoke(((MainActivity) activity).getLastestBarcode());
    }
    else {
      callback.invoke("");
    }
  }

  // Added sendEvent
  private void sendEvent(
    String eventName,
    @Nullable WritableMap params
  ) {
    this.reactContext
      .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
      .emit(eventName, params);
  }


  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "HoneywellCT50";
  }
}
```

In React Native:

```
// I import DeviceEventEmitter
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native'

componentDidMount () {
  // Listen for Honeywell Scans
  DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('BarcodeRecieved', this.getBarcodeValue)
}

// I want to trigger this method
getBarcodeValue () {
  console.log('Event Received')
  // This gets the barcode value, works ok
  HoneywellCT50.latestBarcode((value) => {
    this.setState({ barcode: value })
  })
}
```

With the above code I can build the project with no Java/build errors and I see no JS errors but I cannot trigger the event. Can anyone help point me in the right direction from here?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is emit an event from Java that is sent to JavaScript. You'd write a custom native module, subscribe to its events from JavaScript, and then in your native code you'd emit the event. See this guide: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript

Comment: @ide I have tried to implement a solution based on your answer and I've added the code above. Do you have any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Sending events from Java to JavaScript seems gone in the docs for the latest RN versions (at least 44 and 45)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I got some code working. I'm not sure if this is the best solution but right now I am the limit of my understanding and would welcome any feedback on the following:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onBarcodeEvent(final BarcodeReadEvent event) {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
      String barcodeData = event.getBarcodeData();
      String tstp = event.getTimestamp();
      setLatestBarcode(barcodeData);
      Log.d("MainActivity", " TEST - barcodeData "+ barcodeData + " tstp : "+ tstp);
    }
  });

  WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap(); // <--- added

  getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext() // <--- added
    .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class) // <--- added
    .emit("BarcodeReceived", params); // <--- added
}
```

This works I can trigger a React Method by using the following in my JS:

```
componentWillUnmount () {
  this._barcodeListener.remove()
}

componentWillMount () {
  // Listen for Honeywell Scans
  this.getBarcodeValue = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('BarcodeReceived', this.getBarcodeValue)
}

...

getBarcodeValue () {
  console.log('Event Received')

  HoneywellCT50.latestBarcode((value) => {
    this.setState({ barcode: value }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.barcode)
    })
  })
}
```

If anyone with experience reads this I would love to know why the code posted in my EDIT above didn't work. Is it because I tried emitting the event in a `@ReactMethod` ?

Comment: As @Guillermo Grau pointed out it has been removed from docs. 
Link to the old docs: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript